# Setting up a class identifier to be called when logging array data

Tags: objective-c, c

Hey stackOverflow community. I am working through Big Nerd Ranch's Objective C book and have come across the fun chapter on defining and setting up classes (chapter 17 if you're familiar). In it the challenge has us write a program where we define a stock class with several properties and instance variables. I have been able to get the program to work as asked but I want to tinker a little with it to get it to also NSLog a stockName so I can see what stock is associated with its properties.

Basically, is there a way to make the code more concise for this block:

```
NSString *appleName = @"AppleInc";
[Apple setStockIdentifier:appleName];
```

Maybe more like this:

```
[Apple setStockIdentifier:"AppleInc"];
```

I tried setting the property as a char in the class file but couldnt get it to work. Im new to this but I'm thinking that declaring a new NSString for the stockIdentifier value is extra code that isn't needed. Any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Below is what I have for the main file:

```
 #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
 #import "StockHolding.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

@autoreleasepool {

    StockHolding *Apple = [[StockHolding alloc] init];
    NSString *appleName = @"AppleInc";
    [Apple setStockIdentifier:appleName];
    [Apple setPurchaseSharePrice:2.30];
    [Apple setCurrentSharePrice:4.50];
    [Apple setNumberOfShares:40];

    StockHolding *HomeDepot = [[StockHolding alloc] init];
    NSString *homeDepotName = @"Home Depot Inc";
    [HomeDepot setStockIdentifier:homeDepotName];
    [HomeDepot setPurchaseSharePrice:12.19];
    [HomeDepot setCurrentSharePrice:10.56];
    [HomeDepot setNumberOfShares:90];

    StockHolding *Cisco = [[StockHolding alloc] init];
    NSString *ciscoName = @"Cisco Inc";
    [Cisco setStockIdentifier:ciscoName];
    [Cisco setPurchaseSharePrice:45.10];
    [Cisco setCurrentSharePrice:49.51];
    [Cisco setNumberOfShares:210];

    NSMutableArray *listOfStocks = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:Apple, HomeDepot, Cisco, nil];

    for (StockHolding *currentStock in listOfStocks) {
        NSLog(@"%@, Purchase Share Price: %.2f; Current value: %.2f; Number of shares: %i",[currentStock stockIdentifier],[currentStock purchaseSharePrice], [currentStock currentSharePrice], [currentStock numberOfShares]);
    }


}
return 0;
}
```

Below is the contents of StockHolding.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface StockHolding : NSObject

{
//char stockIdentifier;
float purchaseSharePrice;
float currentSharePrice;
int numberOfShares;
}

@property NSString *stockIdentifier;
@property float purchaseSharePrice;
@property float currentSharePrice;
@property int numberOfShares;

-(float) costInDollars; //purchaseSharePrice * numberOfShares;
-(float) valueInDollars; //currentSharePrice * numberOfShares;

@end
```

And here is StockHolding.m:

```
#import "StockHolding.h"

@implementation StockHolding

@synthesize currentSharePrice, purchaseSharePrice, numberOfShares, stockIdentifier;

-(float)costInDollars;
{
return (purchaseSharePrice * numberOfShares);
}

-(float)valueInDollars;
{
return (currentSharePrice * numberOfShares);
}

@end
```

Comment: The trick is the `@` sign.  When a double-quoted string is proceeded by an `@` sign, the string is of type `NSString`.  Without the `@` sign, it's just a plain old `char *`.

Comment: Just for future reference; If I had the stockIdentifier property set to char would the syntax [Apple setStockIdentifier:"AppleInc"] work?

Comment: Yes and No. Yes because it would be syntactically correct, and therefore would compile.  No, because I think you'll find that objective-C is heavily biased towards using `NSString`.  As long as all of the code is very low level, and avoids using the Apple framework classes and functions, you won't have any problems.  However, as the program expands and becomes more complicated, I expect that you'll be highly motivated to move everything from `char *` to `NSString *`. So it's best just to get in the habit of putting `@` signs in front of all the strings, and use `NSString`s everywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simply a syntax error.

```
[Apple setStockIdentifier:"AppleInc"];
```

Should be...

```
[Apple setStockIdentifier:@"AppleInc"];
```

Comment: Thanks Chris. I swear I had tried that earlier and it wasn't working but I may have had the property set as a char when I did that so that would have been the reason it wouldn't work. Really appreciate this community and help from people like you.